# xticklabels disappear when using ax.twin in subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to create a 2 rows subplots using pandas plot, where the upper subplots has secondary y axis, but the creation of the secondary axis makes the xticklabels disappear as shown below.
I used the following code:

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots(2,1)
ax=axes[0]
pd.Series(range(10)).plot(ax=ax)
ax2=ax.twinx()
(pd.Series(range(10))**2).plot(ax=ax2)

ax=axes[1]
pd.Series(range(10)).plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

when using the same code but replacing the order of the subplots it works fine:

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots(2,1)

ax=axes[0]
pd.Series(range(10)).plot(ax=ax)


ax=axes[1]
pd.Series(range(10)).plot(ax=ax)
ax2=ax.twinx()
(pd.Series(range(10))**2).plot(ax=ax2)
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note:- this is a problem with pandas. If you plot using pure matplotlib this does not happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I suggest using matplotlib as is, and not through pandas. That should solve your issue.

So it would be something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,axes=plt.subplots(2,1)

ax=axes[0]
ax.plot(pd.Series(range(10)))
ax2=ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(pd.Series(range(10))**2)

ax=axes[1]
ax.plot(pd.Series(range(10)))
```

[image: result]